# WMD / bullet lists

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

Is the depth limitation of bullet lists a markdown feature? Or was it introduced in the markdown processor rewrite? I'm talking about:

- data with

  - sub nodes
  - and sub-sub-nodes
  - and so on

which is:

```
 - data with
  - sub nodes
   - and sub-sub-nodes
    - and so on
```

I've seen people struggle to describe object graphs etc. I see it behaves the same [here](http://wmd-editor.com/demo), but is this one of those cases where following the *original* spec is unnecessarily limiting?

Comment: Perhaps using code (formatted via prettify) will be a better choice to represent object graphs/treeviews? You've demonstrated it in your post :)

Comment: Look like you need more spaces before each "-" to get the indention correct. Edit Jeff's post and compare his indentation (4 spaces) to yours (1 space). I did a bit of experimentation and you need at least 3 spaces to get the indentation correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depth limit of bullets?

- item 1

  - item 2

    - item 3

      - item 4

        - item 5

```
- item 1
    - item 2
        - item 3
            - item 4
                - item 5
```

Comment: I stand <s>indented</s> corrected.